# xmpp : XML schema

Tags: xsd, xmpp

I am a beginner in XML schema and XMPP message protocols. Is there any explicit way to understand the below XML schema. What does each tags means and how many types of tags are there - what is the specified way of reading and writing them:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    targetNamespace='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'
    xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'
    elementFormDefault='qualified'>

  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      The protocol documented by this schema is defined in
      XEP-0033: http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>


  <xs:element name='address'>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base='empty'>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base='xs:NCName'>
                <xs:enumeration value='bcc'/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attribute name='uri' use='optional' type='xs:string'/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name='empty'>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
      <xs:enumeration value=''/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: As said in its documentation, go to [`http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html`](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) and you will get the details.

Comment: Just as a note, XMPP schemas are not "normative". That means the text of the specification is the true definition of the protocol, and the schema is for guidance/example only.

Answer (score 0):

XSD is a complex language, and there's no way of giving an adequate explanation in a few paragraphs. Reading the W3C XML Schema Primer (XML Schema Part 0) might be a good start; even better, get Eric van der Vlist's book and read the opening chapters.

The fragment you have given us is not well-formed: it contains an unmatched `</xs:attribute>` end tag at line 26. If we add the missing line:

`<xs:attribute name='type' use='required'>`

at line 21, then the schema is defining rules for an `address` element that has two attributes and no content: a mandatory `type` attribute whose only permitted value is `bcc`, and an optional `uri` attribute whose value is any string. It's a rather odd way to define an element with no content: it's actually defining it as an element that does have content, where the content must be an empty string. Perhaps the schema designers had a reason for this, but it's not immediately obvious.